# Gallery Video and Player Category in Button

Tags: wordpress, web

Good day I'm new in WordPress so I working on a project so im making a video portfolio in the website 1st im using the plugin portfolio but it I want to add a Video player in the same page so the user will not got to other page just to view the video i use responsive filterable portfolio but it was not supported by Vimeo video I have to go premium now in using gallery video and player plugin it work well but the problem is there's no sorting of the video by group how can I add this shortcode parameters `[sp_html5video category=”category_ID”]` to the button so I can sort them by group by clicking the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just edit the video and gallery plugins then at a filter template

```
function html5video_setup_post_types() {

$html5video_labels =  apply_filters( 'sp_html5video_labels', array(
    'name'                => 'Video Gallery',
    'singular_name'       => 'Video Gallery',
    'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Video', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'edit_item'           => __('Edit Video', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'new_item'            => __('New Video', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'all_items'           => __('All Videos', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'view_item'           => __('View Video Gallery', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'search_items'        => __('Search Video Gallery', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'not_found'           => __('No Videos Gallery found', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No Videos Gallery found in Trash', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'parent_item_colon'   => '',
    'menu_name'           => __('Video Gallery', 'html5-videogallery-plus-player'),
    'exclude_from_search' => true
) );
```